# Visual Studio C# console build closes if an error occures, how can I let the console stay open?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

Console application (build) closes if an error occures, how can I let the console stay open after the error occures? (For debbuging reasons, and yes the application has to be build for my purposes)

Console.ReadKey() is not what I am looking for, just wondering if I can prevent the exit on error.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761216/debugging-attach-to-process-for-console-app-running-inside-cmd-exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep console window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952846/how-to-keep-console-window-open)

Comment: can we have some codes ? what type of error is it ? it shouldn't close the console normally

Answer (score 0):

You can use [try, catch, finally] operator to block errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally

Comment: That is about catching exceptions, which the asker might very well be able to. It doesn't solve keeping the console open.

Answer (score -2):

The piece of code which can casue exception should be written inside

```
try{} catch{}
```

Example: In this for loop first iteration should give an Index out bound error but still it continues to print ignoring the exception case. In catch you can do whatever you want to do with the exception.

```
int v = 100;
int[] a = new int[v];
for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)`
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[i - 1].ToString() + " - Count: " + i);
    }
    catch
    {}
}
```

Comment: That is about catching exceptions, which the asker might very well be able to. It doesn't solve keeping the console open.

Comment: @PalleDue Yes, I'm very well aware that concern of the question is to keep the console open. But the context of it is already given that the questioner wants to prevent the closing of console at error. I think my answer pretty well serve the solution for the question asked.